# Apache Gora - java.net.MalformedURLException while creating a hbase datastore

Tags: java, hbase, gora

I am building a project which uses Gora-hbase as backend .
    Hbase is up and running . I am not using maven or ivy .

Also i have specified the following in /conf/gora.properties :

> gora.datastore.default=org.apache.gora.hbase.store.HBaseStore
>           gora.datastore.autocreateschema=true

In my code, i am using the following piece of code to start a datastore :

> datastore =
>   DataStoreFactory.getDataStore(long.class,UserDetails.class,new
>   Configuration());

I am getting the following exception at the above line :

```
13/02/04 23:02:26 INFO zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Session establishment complete on server localhost/127.0.0.1:2181, sessionid = 0x13ca8d9ecac000c, negotiated timeout = 40000
org.apache.gora.util.GoraException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.net.MalformedURLException
    at org.apache.gora.store.DataStoreFactory.createDataStore(DataStoreFactory.java:167)
    at org.apache.gora.store.DataStoreFactory.getDataStore(DataStoreFactory.java:278)
    at com.psl.gora.java.model.TestClass.init(TestClass.java:34)
    at com.psl.gora.java.model.TestClass.<init>(TestClass.java:23)
    at com.psl.gora.java.model.TestClass.main(TestClass.java:47)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.net.MalformedURLException
    at org.apache.gora.hbase.store.HBaseStore.initialize(HBaseStore.java:125)
    at org.apache.gora.store.DataStoreFactory.initializeDataStore(DataStoreFactory.java:102)
    at org.apache.gora.store.DataStoreFactory.createDataStore(DataStoreFactory.java:161)
    ... 4 more
Caused by: java.net.MalformedURLException
    at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:617)
    at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:480)
    at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:429)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLEntityManager.setupCurrentEntity(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLVersionDetector.determineDocVersion(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.jdom.input.SAXBuilder.build(SAXBuilder.java:453)
    at org.jdom.input.SAXBuilder.build(SAXBuilder.java:770)
    at org.apache.gora.hbase.store.HBaseStore.readMapping(HBaseStore.java:524)
    at org.apache.gora.hbase.store.HBaseStore.initialize(HBaseStore.java:111)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:522)
    ... 19 more
```

Is there anything I am missing or am not aware  of?
Any help or suggestion appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

When this stacktrace is shown, probably is because `gora-hbase-mapping.xml` is missing.

This question is from months ago, but if other person has the same problem, maybe this would help.

From `HBaseStore:524` is being called `builder.build(null)` and results are like in http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/262714/

---- Other possibility ----

Try as key class `String.class` and check if it works. (Just checking...)